# Retrieve row of item in Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Is there a method that can retrieve the row of an item in Firebase? Something like `getRow()`?

See example below:
[image]

Comment: Did you have a look at the [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)?

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes Yes, I did & I didn't find what I was looking for. That's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: Ignoring the screenshot for a moment, what do you mean by first/second/etc? Is there some criteria you might be interested in sorting by? With that in mind the docs have what you're looking for, but I can't answer for you directly without more information about your data.

Comment: unless you know the id you boxed in red, you will have to download all the children and get the row clientside through iteration.

Comment: Not entirely true, you can query it based on a field with equalTo() even if you don't know the key boxed in red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Firebase database consists of 1 root node and that node can have subsequent children. When you get the reference of the root directory, add .child(child name) to the end of it. This gives you the name of the child of the root node. To get its value add .getValue()